# How to avoid TypeError when getting array key using Phpstan?

Tags: php, static-analysis, phpstan

```
<?php 

/**
 * @return int[]
 */
function getIntArray(): array
{
    return [100, 200];
}

function setInt(int $value): void
{
    echo $value;
}

$intArray = getIntArray();
setInt($intArray[2]);
```

This code will result in an error:
`PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 2`
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: setInt(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type int, null given`

but phpstan shows no errors:
https://phpstan.org/r/ab7b85e4-2f96-4d6e-9ef7-20c99d5b163a

Is there some kind of setting in phpstan that catches this error?

Comment: There's an open feature request about it: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/7553